# How to store custom class to LocalSettings in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-store-apps, settings

I am porting a Windows Phone 8 app to Windows 8.1 and would like to use ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings to store/persist some data. Beside some String/Bool/Int values I would like to store a (quite simple) custom class as well.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass {
    [DataMember]
    public double Property1;

    [DataMember]
    public int Property2;

    [DataMember]
    public int Property3;

    [DataMember]
    public bool Property4;


    public int Total{
        get { return Property2 + Property 3; }     
        }
    }
}
```

On WP 8 I use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to store the settings without any problem. It works fine even if I do not use DataContract/DataMember:

```
MyClass mySettings = new MyClass();
mySettings.Property2 = 1;
mySettings.Property2 = 2;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mySettings"] = mySettings;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

MyClass loadedSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mySettings"];
Debug.WriteLine(loadedSettings.Total); // == 3
```

The same thing on Win 8.1 results in a serialization exception when using:

```
...
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["mySettings"] = mySettings;


Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IMap`2.Insert(K key, V value)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Insert[K,V](IMap`2 _this, K key, V value)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Indexer_Set[K,V](K key, V value)
```

I found the hint to use DataContract/DataMember but this did not change anything? Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx):

> You can't directly assign other types of objects to app data. You can
>   serialize data to one of the supported data types, for example you can
>   serialize your data as JSON and store it as a string, but you need to
>   handle the serialization.

So you need to serialize objects by yourself or use [ApplicationDataCompositeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx) for grouping.